# How to bind control IsEnable property to some counter

Tags: binding

I want to enable some button only when my counter reach some number (let say 1)

```
int questionCounter;
public int QuestionCounter
{
    get { return questionCounter; }
    set 
    { 
        questionCounter = value;
        if (questionCounter == 1)
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsEnabled"));
    }
}
```

---

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource GoBackButton}"
    x:Name="GoBack" Click="GoBack_Click" Margin="100,10,0,0" 
            IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}, Mode=FindAncestor}}" >
```

and the initial button state is:

```
{button.IsEnabled = False;}
```

but i have no success here...

any help please

Comment: none can help me here ? please

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to bind to the result of a converter

```
public class IsEnabledConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(value) > 0);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And bind it like this

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:IsEnabledConverter x:Key="isEnabledConverter"></local:IsEnabledConverter >
</Window.Resources>
```

[...]

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource GoBackButton}"
    x:Name="GoBack" Click="GoBack_Click" Margin="100,10,0,0" 
            IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled,  Converter={StaticResource isEnabledConverter}}" />
```